# MySQL: Limiting the count of records returned for each player in result set

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, recordset

### How can I change the following query to limit the results such that for each person, only two games appear rather than four?

This will allow me to more easily answer the question, which two games have each of these people played most recently? Or similar questions with large sets where many records are returned for each person.

I use the following SQL in MySQL through phpMyAdmin to return a list of games for a group of a few people that answers the question, for this group of people, what are some games they have played most recently?

Currently all the different games each person has played appear in the results. I'm wondering if I can limit the number of games listed for each person to two for example. Then I could answer the above question more easily.

playgroup.Fullname is a table that has the four people I want to create the list for.

---

### Query

```
SELECT Games.Title, playgroup.FullName, Max(Responses.PlayDate)

FROM (Players INNER JOIN (Games INNER JOIN Responses ON Games.ID = Responses.Title) ON Players.ID = Responses.Player) INNER JOIN PlayGroup ON Players.ID = PlayGroup.FullName

GROUP BY Games.Title, PlayGroup.FullName

ORDER BY playgroup.FullName ASC, Max(Responses.PlayDate) DESC;
```

---

### Current Results

#### What change to the query could result in only two games be returned for each FullName?

```
Title,
FullName,
Max(Responses.PlayDate)

Dutch Blitz
1
2020-06-14 00:00:00.000000

PitchCar
1
2020-06-13 00:00:00.000000

Bohnanza
1
2020-05-31 00:00:00.000000

Geocaching
1
2020-05-25 00:00:00.000000

Patchwork
2
2020-05-26 00:00:00.000000

Dominion
2
2020-05-25 00:00:00.000000

Geocaching
2
2020-05-25 00:00:00.000000

Disc Golf
2
2020-05-24 00:00:00.000000

Dutch Blitz
4
2020-06-14 00:00:00.000000

Bohnanza
4
2020-05-31 00:00:00.000000

Ingenious
4
2020-04-28 00:00:00.000000

Qwirkle
4
2020-04-08 00:00:00.000000

Colossal Arena
141
2020-06-19 00:00:00.000000

Roll for the Galaxy
141
2020-06-18 00:00:00.000000

Fortnite
141
2020-06-16 00:00:00.000000

Pendragon
141
2020-06-15 00:00:00.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT title, fullname, max_playdate
FROM (SELECT g.Title, pg.FullName, Max(r.PlayDate) as max_playdate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY g.Title ORDER BY MAX(r.PlayDate) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Players p INNER JOIN
           Games g INNER JOIN
           Responses r
           ON r.ID = r.Title JOIN
           Players p
           ON p.ID = r.Player INNER JOIN
           PlayGroup pg
           ON p.ID = pg.FullName    
      GROUP BY g.Title, pg.FullName
     ) g
ORDER BY FullName ASC, max_PlayDate DESC;
```